# auditbeat failure in ELK : index_not_found_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I followed the guidelines to install auditbeats in ELK to send my auditd logs to ELK, but unfortunately I just can't seem to be able to make it work. I checked my config files multiple times and I just can't wrap my head around it. When I lookup the index "auditbeat-*" in Kibana, it finds no results at all.

When I check the state of the module itself, I get :

```
curl localhost:9200/auditbeat-6.2.1-2018.02.14/_search?pretty
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
      "reason" : "no such index",
      "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
      "resource.id" : "auditbeat-6.2.1-2018.02.14",
      "index" : "auditbeat-6.2.1-2018.02.14"
    } ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "auditbeat-6.2.1-2018.02.14",
    "index" : "auditbeat-6.2.1-2018.02.14"
  },
  "status" : 404
}
```

so I am not sure where to take it from there. I tried sending those via both ElasticSearch and Logstach but I keep getting the same results no matter what.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out this is happening because the port is bound to address 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0.